# Call of Java Method via Javascript not working in Simulator

Tags: codenameone

Clicking the Button does nothing - but why.

The click on the button should print "[Javascript Logger] Aha".

Here the code:

```
public class FormNotCalled extends Form {
    public FormNotCalled() {
        setTitle("FormNotCalled");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setScrollable(false);
        BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();
        browserComponent.setPage(
                "<html lang=\"en\\\">\n" + 
                "    <body >\n" + 
                "        <button onclick=\"logger.log('Aha');\">Click me</button>\n" + 
                "    </body>\n" + 
                "</html>", 
                null);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browserComponent);
        JavascriptContext javascriptContext = new JavascriptContext(browserComponent);
        JSObject logger = (JSObject)javascriptContext.get("{}");
        logger.set("log", new JSFunction() {
            public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                String msg = (String)args[0];
                Log.p("[Javascript Logger] " + msg);
            }

        });
        javascriptContext.set("window.logger", logger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need the logger set to be before the setPage call?

Answer (score 1):

setPage() is asynchronous.  You need to wait until the page is loaded before registering functions on it.  The easiest way to do this is inside the onLoad event.

e.g.

```
browserComponent.addWebEventListener(e->{
        JSObject logger = (JSObject)javascriptContext.get("{}");
        logger.set("log", new JSFunction() {
            public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
                String msg = (String)args[0];
                Log.p("[Javascript Logger] " + msg);
            }

        });
        javascriptContext.set("window.logger", logger);
});
```

Comment: Doing the initialization on onLoad doesn't make a change:
   browserComponent.addWebEventListener("onLoad", (e) -> Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    JavascriptContext javascriptContext = new JavascriptContext(browserComponent);
    JSObject logger = (JSObject)javascriptContext.get("{}");
    logger.set("log", new JSFunction() {
        public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
            String msg = (String)args[0];
            Log.p("[Javascript Logger] " + msg);
        }
  
    });
    javascriptContext.set("window.logger", logger);
   }));

Comment: Surprisingly when loading the HTML via `com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent.setURLHierarchy(String)` it works but throws a FileNotFound exception